# Actions on Google context not being passed to next intent

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I am trying to pass values from one intent to another.
This is how I set the context:

```
app.intent('welcome', async (conv) => {
    const parameters = {
      userId: "12345"
    };
    conv.contexts.set('userDoc', 5, parameters);
    conv.followup('second', {})
})
```

This is how I try to retrieve the context parameters:

```
app.intent('second', (conv) => {
  console.log(conv.userDoc); // returns undefined
})
```

However, conv.userDoc returns undefined.

This is my dialogflow setup:

[image: dialogflow welcome screen]
[image: dialogflow second screen]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Contexts are set as part of the *reply* that is sent back. Calling `conv.followup()` discards everything from the reply except for the event type and parameters that are sent.

In general - you probably don't want to actually use `conv.followup()` anyway. If you feel you need to return something from your webhook - just return it.